# How to change form from get to post?

Tags: php, post

the links of this form have question marks:

This is a file: sidebar.php

```
echo
<form method='get'>
    <div class='left'>
     <div class='btn-group-vertical'> 
             <!-- Vertically Stck button group -->
       <button 'submit' name='Service)name' class='btn btn-default'>Service Name</button>
       <button type='submit' name='YYY_Service' class='btn btn-default'>YYY Service</button>

      </div>
      </form>; 
      ?>
```

This is a part of index.php:

```
ini_set('session.save_path','/path/to/session');
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$current_menu='empty.php'; //If no menu/button is selected get right column empty(empty.php)


if(isset($_REQUEST['Service'])){$current_menu='serviceform.php';}
if(isset($_REQUEST['YYY_Service'])){$current_menu='yyyform.php';}
```

This is showing URLS such as:

```
www.foo.com/index.php?Service=
www.foo.com/index.php?YYY_Service=
```

How should this form changed in order to show instead urls this way?

```
www.foo.com/serviceform.php
www.foo.com/yyyform.php
```

And this code in another file:

```
function Button_set($name, $newline)
{

   if($newline){
   ?>
    <br><br><input type="button" name="<?=$name?>" value="<?=$name?>" /input>
   <?php
   }
   else if (!$newline){
   ?>
    <input type="button" name="<?=$name?>" value="<?=$name?>" /input>
   <?php
   }

 }
```

If I only change the form method to POST it doesn't work...

Comment: The code producing the URL's isn't shown here.

Comment: I think I found it, and added it above. Is that the one you were looking for?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the code either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
<form method="get">
```

to:

```
<form method="post">
```

Also add attribute "action" to site you want:

```
<form method="post" action="serviceform.php">

<form method="post" action="yyyform.php">
```

[W3C link on form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Comment: Hmm, here every button should redirect to a different php file. If I go to these files manually, for example `www.foo.com/serviceform.php` I shows up full screen. But the purpose here is for every button to show the page on the right column, without question mark.

Comment: If you want only to use buttons as a link then use <a href="www.foo.com/serviceform.php">serviceform</a>